# Coin change algorithm always returning one

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, coin-change

```
/**
 * 
 * @param d
 *            currency divisions
 * @param p
 *            target
 * @return number of coins
 */
public static int change(int[] d, int p) {
    int[] tempArray = new int[p*2]; // tempArray to store set
                                                    // of coins forming
                                                    // answer
    for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) { // cycling up to the wanted value
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //assigning current minimum number of coints
        for (int value : d) {//cycling through possible values
            if (value <= i) {
                if (1 + tempArray[i - value] < min) { //if current value is less than min
                    min = 1 + tempArray[1 - value];//assign it
                }
            }
        }
        tempArray[i] = min; //assign min value to array of coins
    }
    return tempArray[p];
}
```

Can anyone help me see why this is not working please? The method is meant to be given an input of values representing coins, it has an infinite number of these coints with which to form the integer p, the method is to return the minimum number of coins used to get to p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tempArray is initialized to 0 on all indices.
using tempArray[1-value] is basically giving you 0.
So, all indices from 1 to p has the value 1 + tempArray[1-value] 
This is 1. Also, tempArray[1-value] is a negetive index. I think you meant tempArray[i-value]

Comment: Brilliant, I just changed the line you mentioned from 1-value to i-value and it works. Do you think this is now correct? I am really confused with what is actually happening line by line as well, could you please give me a brief overview?

Comment: It incrementally checks for every integer from 1 to p, the minimum number of denominations needed to get the value, if you want to know how many coins of denominations {1,2,3,4} will you need to make a total of 10. the code starts with 1, checks the minimum number of coins needed, then for 2, then for 3, so on. You could consider this, as splitting the 10 into 4+4+2, at 4 the value is 1, at 8 the value is 2 and finally at 10 the value is 3. You can see what is going on by printing the values of min at the end of each iteration